# Validate password hashed in Django using BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher in Node.js app

Tags: django, node.js, django-authentication, bcrypt, sha256

I am trying to migrate some users created in a Django app over to a Node.js app. Users created in the Django app have had their pssswords hashed using the BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher hasher and these are stored in a PostgreSQL database. I am able to get the whole password string from Postgres where these are stored in the form:

```
<algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>.
```

What I am trying to do is figure out how to take a known password (say Password1) and, using the salt from the field in Postgres, get the Node.js hashed string to match the Django string. In this way I can authenticate those users who have been migrated over.

I have made several attempts at using the bcrypt and bcryptjs npm's for Node.js but so far I'm having no luck.

A working example using any of the Node.js npm's would be great.

Comment: Have you checked source code of `BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher` to check exact alghoritm?

Comment: Indeed I had a look through the source, but I'm not very familiar with Python and its libraries and the problem is more how to achieve the same result in Node.js

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure this out after a fair bit of trial & error. This is the solution:

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

exports.auth = function (password) {
    var preHash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password).digest('hex');
    var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(preHash, salt);

    return hash;
}
```

where the salt parameter should for example be:

```
$2a$12$imuoSFEBx8JJh5L9cCDJKO
```

The only thing I am still unclear on is the first part of the salt string '$2a$'. In my Django password field this is actually '$2b$' which according to the [bcrypt page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) is valid, yet when trying to use $2b$ in the salt passed to bcrypt (and bcryptjs too) an error is thrown. I can work around this but perhaps bcrypt just needs to be updated.